# Does the "Scenic Ribbon" need MS licensing?

Tags: licensing, ribbon

The new variant "Scenic Ribbon" is now part of the Windows API (the Office 2007 "Fluent Ribbon" was not).

Does anyone know if a program that uses the "Scenic Ribbon" needs to go through the licensing process like a program that uses the "Fluent" variant of the ribbons?

Waht is if the program does not use the original Windows API but a 3rd party toolkit that mimics the layout of the "Scenic Ribbon"? - Would that be a special case for licensing?

Comment: Here's a secondary question.  I thought UI concepts were not patentable or protectable, so couldn't you, in theory, clone it with your own code?  I am aware that this is a horrible amount of work, I'm just curious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/2006/11/21/licensing-the-2007-microsoft-office-user-interface.aspx), it does requires licensing.

The license let you use the CONCEPT of the ribbon and it is not restricted to any implementation or platform. This means that if you buy a third party ribbon control running on a MAC you should get the license, but also if you use Microsoft free implementation of the scenic ribbon.

Getting the license is not a major restriction provided that you are not competing with one of the office applications.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft require you to get a license to use the Ribbon concept in your application(either Fluent or Scenic variations). I presume this is an effort to prevent other platforms (Linux, Mac etc...) from using the same idea in their software.

But I have no idea if this requirement is legally valid or if they have any chance of enforcing it. I guess we will not know until it appears on the Mac as an Apple implementation and a court battle then ensues!